# New to JSON - trouble with unset/clear/delete json array

Tags: arrays, json, unset

Currently trying this:

```
unset($jsonArr-[$json]);
```

but I get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ')'

This has to be simple to do. I've been searching for an answer to this for hours. I think I've tried everything listed on this site. I'm pulling `lat` and `lng` from mapquest and I need to clear the array to do the next record.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&Format=json&inFormat=json&json={location:{street:%22$address%22},options:{thumbMaps:false,maxResults:1}}');
$jsonArr = json_decode($json);

$lat = $jsonArr->results[0]->locations[0]->latLng->lat;
$lon = $jsonArr->results[0]->locations[0]->latLng->lng;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE - Totally not the array not clearing, it was the variable in the address.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why won't `unset($jsonArr);` do what you want?

Comment: No matter what address I enter I get the same lat and lon, through a process of elimination it looks like $jsonArr is not clearing when I run it.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else. `$jsonArr` will be set to something by `json_decode()`, even if the parsing process fails. It's more likely that your call to the API is always returning the same values. You should use `var_dump($json)` immediately after you request the data to make sure you're getting what you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the array you simply

```
unset($jsonArr);
```